# Why is '>' a valid comparison with VARCHAR data in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm pretty brand new to SQL (and scripting/coding in general) and this is from one of the examples in the book, but they, unfortunately, decided that there wouldn't be any questions about this query and neglected to expand on the '>' near the end of the query

Here is the query in question:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM easy_drinks 
 WHERE main > 'soda';
```

Here is a pastebin of a few queries, hopefully giving the perspective needed: http://pastebin.com/xfJQsBvU

Paste of DESC easy_drinks: http://pastebin.com/LZZPhk6Z

I'm just confused as to how the '>' near the end of the query is working, since main is stored as a VARCHAR and 'soda' is definitely not an integer than could be compared with another integer.  Yet, as you can see in the first pastebin, the query completes successfully.  Why doesn't MySQL return an error and what is the pattern behind the different queries using '>' and '<'?

Answer (score 7):

It's probably doing a [lexicographical ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

It's similar to the way you or I would order words in a dictionary. However, note that it [may not handle numbers the way you'd expect](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html).

Answer (score 0):

You will often find > -relations on strings, mostly used for alphabetical order, but of course it is implementation dependent, and can be different especially for different languages/encodings or for the question of upper- and lowercase.

Comment: In an ideal SQL implementation, you'd be able to define a type (known in SQL as a `DOMAIN`) inherited from `VARCHAR` and overload its operators including `>`.